# How do I execute a remote alias over an SSH?

Tags: bash, ssh, command-line, alias

How do I execute a remote alias over an SSH?

---

For instance, there is a rather complex alias for `rkhunter`, and I would like to execute it in one command over `ssh` like that:

```
ssh user@server_ip -p port_number -t alias_name_defined_on_server
```

To be exact, the alias is defined in `.bash_aliases` which is sourced by `.bashrc` of this particular `user`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[A working answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22540192/5088142) was published in SO, quoted below:

> Quoted from the man page of `bash`: *Aliases are not expanded when
>   the shell is not interactive, unless the expand_aliases shell option
>   is set using shopt ...*
>
> So the simplest way IMO is to put the following lines at the top of
>   your `/home/<user>/.bashrc` file:
>
> ```
> # comment out the original line
> # [ -z "$PS1" ] && return
>
> if [ -z "$PS1" ]; then
>   shopt -s expand_aliases
>   # alias ls='ls --color=always'
>   # return
> fi
> ```
>
> Save and exit. Now you can run `ssh user@host "your_alias"`
>   successfully.

Note: If your `~/.bashrc` hold something like the below, comment the line that `return` when the shell is not interactive:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
 case $- in
     *i*) ;;
       *) return;;
 esac
```